# How to create an object in this format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an object to be sent in an AJAX request in the format I need.
In the code I'm able to get the `name` attribute for each `input` element and its value, but I need to create an object in the below format. How can I create that?

```
{
  "userrole":"",
  "userAttributes":{
    "username":"alks",
    "useraddress":"ajdaa",
    "usercity":"lajsdk"
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="data-fields-container">
  <div class="input-type" data-attr-name="userrole">
    <input type="text" name="userrole">
  </div>
  <div class="input-type" data-attr-name="username">
    <input type="text" name="username">
  </div>            
  <div class="input-type" data-attr-name="useraddress">
    <input type="text" name="useraddress">
  </div>
  <div class="input-type" data-attr-name="usercity">
    <input type="text" name="usercity">
    </div>
  </div>    
  <button id="submit_data">Submit</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_data').on('click', function() {
    $('.data-fields-container > .input-type').each(function() {
      dataobj = {};
      var attrkey = $(this).attr('data-attr-name');
      var attrval = $(this).find('input').val();
    })

    $.ajax(function() {
      url: "https://map.net/api/v44",
      data: dataobj,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'Json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('successful')
      },
      error: function(request, error) {
        console.log('failed')
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Just FYI there's no such thing as a 'JSON object'. JSON is a method of serialising a data structure so that it can be transferred. What you're trying to create is simply an object. I've edited the question to remove references to JSON as it's not relevant to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the `serializeArray()` result and construct your object like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_data').on('click', function() {
    var dataobj = {userrole: $('[name="userrole"]').val()};

    var attr = $('.data-fields-container input:not([name="userrole"])').serializeArray().map(function(o) {
      this[o.name] = o.value;
      return this;
    }.bind({}))[0];

    dataobj['userAttributes'] = attr;

    console.log(dataobj);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-fields-container">
  <div class="input-type" data-attr-name="userrole">
    <input type="text" name="userrole">
  </div>

  <div class="input-type" data-attr-name="username">
    <input type="text" name="username">
  </div>

  <div class="input-type" data-attr-name="useraddress">
    <input type="text" name="useraddress">
  </div>

  <div class="input-type" data-attr-name="usercity">
    <input type="text" name="usercity">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="submit_data">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataObj = {
    "userrole":document.querySelector('div.input-type input[name="userrole"]').value,
    "userAttributes":{
        "username":document.querySelector('div.input-type input[name="username"]').value,
        "useraddress":document.querySelector('div.input-type input[name="useraddress"]').value,
        "usercity":document.querySelector('div.input-type input[name="usercity"]').value
    }
}
```

You don't need to iterate through the inputs since your JSON format is static.